# Loop through a dictionary in C# with a list of values

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary

```
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> myDic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(2)
{
    {"Key1", new List<string> {"Val1", "Val2", "Val3"} },
    {"Key2", new List<string> {"Val4", "Val5"} }
};
```

I want to loop through the keys with the count of values for each key.

I have tried

```
foreach (string key in myDic.Keys)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myDic.Values.Count; i++)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

which is obviously not working but I can't think of a better way.

//do something has to be executed for the keys a specific number of times as per the number of values. How can I go about this?

Comment: How many `List` items are you thinking there are in the Dictionary for `Key1` and `Key2`? For those two items, I only see one item in each of them. Perhaps your test/sample data is setup incorrectly with missing double-quotes ?

Comment: I have several List items.. You're right, the double quotes are missing. I will correct that, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like with out testing it.

```
foreach (var keyValuePair in myDic)
{
    Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair.Key);
    foreach (var s in keyValuePair.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Or with index forloop

```
foreach (var keyValuePair in myDic)
{
    Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair.Key);
    for (int i = 0; i < keyValuePair.Value.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair.Value[i]);
    }
}
```